# QGIS - Problem with optional layers in model builder

Tags: model, option-type, layer, qgis, designer

I am trying to make a model with an input layer (polygon) but I want it as optional, because I do not need it always. If not, I have to create it. I want to avoid this useless work.

Is the case of the algorithm "Difference": when I set an input layer as optional, and the algorithm "Difference" receives that it does not exist a layer that the algorithm needs, the model crashes.

Is there a way to implement a conditional (by means of a boolean or IF) for example like this (in the "Difference" algorithm):

if (@Optional_Layer = true, @OUTPUT_Other_Algorithm, "nothing" or "")

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a relatively simple task to solve in a [python processing script](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html).

There is however a [conditional branch](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/modelertools.html#conditional-branch) modeler only tool/algorithm. Unfortunately, it does to my knowledge not support your specific use case, as it still will throw an error if no input layer is supplied for an algorithm.

You could however build an - admittedly a little bit clumsy - workaround with a dummy layer (just an empty layer with no features) and a conditional branch: The empty dummy layer is feed into the model if you do not want a specific algorithm/branch of the model (in your case "difference") to run. You just need a condition to check, if the input layer is a dummy layer or a real layer (see below for a simple example):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
The problem is that this "Difference" algorithm has another conditional branch related to the process. As far as I know, it is not possible to assign two different conditions to a single algorithm.